# C.S. Lewis's view of Scripture vs. Chicago Statements on Biblical Inerrancy & Hermeneutics

Tags: evangelicalism, cs-lewis, inerrancy

#### Background of the question

It has been widely recognized that C.S. Lewis's view of Scripture is complicated, situated between two extremes:

- Late 19th century fundamentalist inerrancy concept which holds that every word is historical and literal truth (if the passage at least allows that possibility), which created the necessity of six 24-hour day creation, for example.  This view is heavily linked with Biblicism, see 2020 article by Michael Bird: [What is Biblicism?](https://www.patheos.com/blogs/euangelion/2020/08/what-is-biblicism/)
- Karl Barth's view that Scripture is privileged human document set apart as canonical "witness" until it becomes the inspired Word of God in the heart of believers (see Justin Elmers's 2020 three-part articles on Karl Barth and the Word of God from Evangelical perspective: [Part 1](https://academic.logos.com/karl-barth-doctrine-of-the-word-of-god-part-1-of-3/), [Part 2](https://academic.logos.com/evangelical-critiques-of-barths-view-of-scripture-part-2-of-3/), and [Part 3](https://academic.logos.com/assessing-barths-evangelical-interlocutors/)).

In the evangelical circles, many pastors and theologians have expressed their concern that C.S. Lewis cannot be considered an Evangelical when it comes to Scripture, because even though Evangelicals have moved on from the 19th century fundamentalist inerrancy concept, C.S. Lewis's view still falls short of what most Evangelicals hold as the "gold standard": the [Chicago Statement on Biblical Inerrancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Statement_on_Biblical_Inerrancy) (1978) which is accompanied later by the Chicago Statement on Biblical Hermeneutics (1982) and the Chicago Statement on Biblical Application (1986).  Thus we find articles such as these:

- 2016 article [The Mixed Blessing of C.S. Lewis](https://sharperiron.org/article/mixed-blessing-of-c-s-lewis-part-1) by Pastor Gary Gilley
- 2015 article [Four Things CS Lewis Said About the Bible That Shook My Faith](https://www.patheos.com/blogs/barrierbreaker/four-things-cs-lewis-said-about-the-bible-that-shook-my-faith/)
- 2003 *The Trinity Review* article [Did C.S. Lewis Go to Heaven?](https://www.trinityfoundation.org/PDF/The%20Trinity%20Review%200205a%20DidCSLewisGotoHeaven.pdf) by John W. Robbins

At the same time, C.S. Lewis never claimed to be a professional theologian and never explicitly promoted a certain doctrine of Scripture.  Instead, the main goals of his Christian writings are

- for his fellow 20th century people to critically see the falsity of modern assumptions in culture, science, and philosophy and to take away modern objections to Christianity
- to share his experience in encountering Christ in his journey from atheism to idealism to theism and finally to Trinitarian Christianity, and from then on to aide Christians in their Christian life by sharing how he overcome or deal with his own difficulties with his sins, his longings, grief, his instinctive distaste with church life, apparent contradictions in Scripture, reconciliation with science, etc.
- to offer *fresh perspective* through his writings in many genres (philosophical, fantasy, essays, children's literature, etc.) to understand our problem (the need for salvation), the gospel (the good news), and what God is doing to help us (as the agent of our salvation)

**so that people can encounter Christ without baggage and clouds of erroneous assumptions**.  The Bible is rarely the focus, but mostly stays in the background.

#### The Question

Given the unease and the love-hate relationship many evangelicals feel toward C.S. Lewis, especially with C.S. Lewis's view of Scriptures (which he expressed only tangentially in his writings or in personal letters, EXCEPT against liberals), **what is the definitive and scholarly comparison between C.S. Lewis's view of Scripture and the Chicago statements on Biblical Inerrancy & Hermeneutics?**

The answer should not pick and choose quotes or take them out of context without considering the implied respect and authority of the Bible in his other writings.

#### Helpful Resources for an answer

- 2013 lecture [Inerrancy and the Patron Saint of Evangelicalism: C.S. Lewis on Holy Scripture](https://www.desiringgod.org/messages/inerrancy-and-the-patron-saint-of-evangelicalism-c-s-lewis-on-holy-scripture)
- Spring 2010 Issue article in C.S. Lewis Institute's journal *Knowing & Doing* [The Inerrancy of Scripture](https://www.cslewisinstitute.org/The_Inerrancy_of_Scripture_FullArticle) by Kevin J. Vanhoozer
- 2010 article in *Sehnsucht: The C.S. Lewis Journal* [C.S. Lewis on Scripture and the Christ, the Word of God: Convergence and Divergence with Karl Barth](https://www.jstor.org/stable/48580098) by P.H. Brazier
- 2012 *BioLogos* article: [Surprised by Jack: C.S. Lewis on Mere Christianity, the Bible, and Evolutionary Science](https://biologos.org/articles/surprised-by-jack-c-s-lewis-on-mere-christianity-the-bible-and-evolutionary-science) by David Williams

Comment: What constitutes "what is the definitive and scholarly" beyond the sources you already cite?

Comment: @guest37 I'm using "definitive" to signal "un-challengeable", precise, fact-based, with citations, considering all relevant evidence so it's unlikely to be wrong if another unconsidered but relevant piece of C.S. Lewis writing can be shown to dispute it.  An answer can very well be derived from the helpful resources section; it was a result of a quick search, I haven't dug deep into them.  They are my notes if I were to write an answer myself (which I probably will).  And yes, I would consider all 4 sources to be an example of "scholarly" since the authors are credentialed/seminary graduates.

Comment: @guest37 My aim for the question (and I may have to revise the question a little to make this clearer) is to characterize C.S. Lewis's position on Scripture *vis a vis* the Evangelical doctrines **without** selling him short and mischaracterizing his view as a liberal Christian who uses the German historical criticism for example.  I think the right location should be somewhere between Chicago and Barth.  One way to answer this question is to show where precisely that location IS by discussing **how he's in agreement / disagreement with specific points in the Chicago statement**.

Comment: I doubt he would accept the Chicago Statement.  He was a very logical thinker.

Comment: @guest37 It's very clear that he wouldn't, not even the precursor of it.  [Philip Ryken's 2013 lecture](https://www.desiringgod.org/messages/inerrancy-and-the-patron-saint-of-evangelicalism-c-s-lewis-on-holy-scripture) pretty much contains the answer I'm looking for.  Maybe to make the question more interesting I should change the question to compare/contrast with Eastern Orthodox, to post-Vatican II Roman Catholic church, and to Karl Barth in addition to Chicago.  An answer with a table of comparison between the 5 would be good, one row for each aspect of infallibility / inerrancy.

Comment: @GreatfulDisciple This is a great question but it's also not easy to answer without having the familiarity with the issue that you yourself have, or greater. I suggest you take the unusual step of answering your own question. I for one would like to read it.

Comment: @DanFefferman Yes, one would need to be knowledgeable in all pertinent C.S. Lewis's works and also on the history of evangelical doctrine of inerrancy (leading to Chicago and also the decades since then) in order to be fair to both.  One day I would simply summarize Philip Ryken's lecture for an answer because having read much both C.S. Lewis and inerrancy, I think his lecture is fair to both.  Expanding the question to other traditions (Orthodox, Catholics, etc.) would be too much an undertaking for an answer author.